# Team cohesion in football manager starting squad/reserves

Tags: football-manager-2013, football-manager-2014, football-manager-2012

In real life football, teams that are not sticking to a predetermined starting squad with the necessary rotation in between don't perform so well because players don't seem to blend in well together. This usually happens on the start of the season when a teams manager hasn't yet determined what are the capabilities of their players/new transfers.

I am on a streak of very disheartening performances in the start of the season and I have started to worry it's mainly because I rotate too much, if that's a thing.

My team is composed of several experienced players and a few hot potential youngsters. Unfortunately I don't have the time to manage my u20 squad and I have placed those promising young lads in my senior squad, making them available to U20 until they are match fit and starting them in a few matches of my senior team as well.

Have you ever experienced bad results cause of too many rotations? Is that even a thing in manager games like in real life? My assistant manager reports that the team has blend in well together and most of the players seem to have forged good relations between them but that's not actually showing on the pitch despite a very talented squad.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is a thing. I cannot say to what extent, but the game does track how much you change your starting lineup.

My own (completely anecdotal) experience with FM2014 indicates the effect is small, maybe even non-existent as long as you only rotate a single player or two. It is unlikely to be your main reason for bad performances.